# What is Yennefer thinking about?

Tags: the-witcher

At the end of [Blood of Elves](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_of_Elves), Yennefer and Ciri have the following exchange (emphasis mine):

> “Lady Yennefer?”
>
> “Yes.”
>
> “What are you looking at like that?”
>
> “At that tree. That linden tree.”
>
> “And what’s so interesting about it?”
>
> **“Nothing. I’m simply feasting my eyes on it. I’m happy that . . . I can see it.”**
>
> “I don’t understand.”
>
> “Good.”
>
> Silence. No words. Humid.

What is the meaning of Yennefer's words? Is she remembering some fond memory with Geralt?

Please avoid spoilers of future books in your answers.

Comment: "*Before she met Ciri, Yennefer lost her sight during Battle of Sodden which happened during SoD. It was later magically restored but for a while she was blind. This is mentioned near the end of Baptism of Fire*" - https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/521rvt/significance_of_a_linden_tree/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Valorum's comment is correct: Yennefer did indeed lost her sight, as we are told by Triss in *Blood of Elves*, chapter three:

> Damn it, I’m Triss Merigold, the Fourteenth One Killed at Sodden. There are fourteen graves at the foot of the obelisk on the Hill, but only thirteen bodies. You’re amazed such a mistake could have been made? Most of the corpses were in hard-to-recognise pieces—no one identified them. The living were hard to account for, too. Of those who had known me well, Yennefer was the only one to survive, and **Yennefer was blind**. Others knew me fleetingly and always recognised me by my beautiful hair. And I, damn it, didn’t have it any more!
>    <sub>Emphasis mine, translation by David French</sub>

Battle of Sodden happened during the "Something More" short story, which, I believe, finishes the *Sword of Destiny* anthology.

Comment: This part is is easy to miss, as some dialogues in that book are purely graphomanic.

Comment: She lost her sigh? That's a very specific thing to lose... /sigh.

Comment: There are other subtle hints in what Yennefer says in the books, for example "I haven't seen anybody for some time".

Comment: Or, Yennefer's letter *"...I now feel well; the period of indisposition is behind me..."*